# How do you create icons/images at address bar

Tags: firefox, favicon

This is a pretty staright question I guess,How do we create images over the left of address bar like images or icons. Few examples are mentioned here [Joel](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/) whose personal image is embeded on far left of address bar and 
[Mashable](http://mashable.com/) you can see 'M'. Surprisingly these images/Icons are only displayed in Firefox. Do we need to use any special tags or something.

Thanks

**EDIT**

In chrome for some reason you can see the icon only if the tab is not in focus. This is not the case in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add a [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) to your project.

This in an image file (usually named 'favicon.ico') that lives in the root directory of your website.

Most browsers will automatically display this image in the address bar if it exists in the root directory.

There is lots of tools for creating a favicon.  Here is one I found via a quick search for 'favicon' - http://www.favicon.cc/